# What are some features of trees (graph theory)?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I understand that trees have a center and longest path(s). Are there any other features trees have? Also, are there different types of "longest paths"?

I'm really sorry if this question doesn't make sense, but I wasn't able to find a lot of information on this online.

Comment: Any two vertices in a tree is connected via a unique path. Any tree has at least 2 leaves. A tree is maximally acyclic and minimally connected.

Comment: @JustWandering Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There are two features of trees that I always found interesting. First, they are minimally connected: the removal of any edge creates a disconnected graph; second, they are maximally acyclic on their set of vertices: joining any two vertices with a new edge produces a cycle.

So, trees are delicately balanced between diconnected graphs and graphs with cycles.

A standard way to define length of a path in a tree is by the number of edges it uses. However, one may assign weights to each edge and interpret the length of a path as the sum of the weights of the edges in the path. This setup allows for the somewhat disconcerting situation in which a path using more edges may actually be "shorter" than one using fewer edges.

EDIT: Re my comment to Neal. I have been sloppy. I am thinking in terms of paths connecting arbitrary pairs of vertices, not a specific pair. So, the path connecting a particular pair of vertices may use fewer edges than the path connecting a different pair, yet still be longer due to the weights of the edges in the two paths,

Comment: How might that disconcerting situation arise in a tree since given any two points there's a unique path connecting them that is a subset of any other path connecting them?

Comment: @Neal - I have perhaps confused things. I am thinking of paths that connect pairs of vertices, not paths that connect a specific pair of vertices. So two vertices connected by two edges of weights 50 and 25, is longer than a path joining two other vertices consisting of 10 edges each of weight 1. Clearly, if two vertices are specified, there is a unique path between them (in a tree) or the graph has to have a cycle.

Comment: @ChrisLeary Ahh, I see what you are saying. I hadn't realized that edges in trees can have weights too, so that is really helpful. Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed response!! :)